# How to apply memorylessness property into solving this question? what is my understanding of that property lacking?

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

> In a city there's $a$ road lamps. the life time of each lamp is exponential with expected value of $b$ months and the life times of different lamps are independent. 
> In the start of the year, all the lamps are working, and whenever a lamp breaks, we change it immediately with a new lamp. 
> What is the probability that no lamp breaks between the hours $2:00$ and $3:00$, in the morning of the first day of february? (you can assume that in each month there's $30$ days).

What I immediately got after reading the question, that the time between each lamp break, is just a random variable which is the minimum of all the exponentials of every lamp, and that is known to have distribution of $exp(a\frac{1}{b})$. (sum of all the expected values of all the lamps), and let's call it $X$. 
Now what I want to calculate is the probability of no lamp breaking inbetween $2-3$, but first I converted them to months, which gives us $\frac{2}{720},\frac{3}{720}$. 
Now I really want to say that from memorylessness property, we can assume that $\frac{2}{720}$ is our start, and we need $X>\frac{1}{720}$ in order to have no lamps burnt in between these two hours. 
But for some reason it doesn't feel alright with me, I know that for memorylessness: $P(X>s+t|X>t)=P(X>s)$. 
And for example $E(X+Y|X>Y)=E(X)$, or in simple words, the probability of my random variable $X$ being greater than something knowing that my random variable is greater than $a$, is the same as the probability of my random variable being greater than something$-a$. 
I'm not sure how to fit my understanding of memorylessness property (if I really understand it..) into this question, what extra information I know about my random variable $X$ that I could use this property here?
I would really appreciate any help in how to connect my understanding of memorylessness property to this question, or pointing out what's wrong with my understanding of memorylessness property if I understood it wrong.

Comment: You are correct and it's not clear to me what doesn't feel right. However, you are maybe overcomplicating things: since the lifetime is exponentially distributed, it follows that the number of failures on a fixed time interval (one hour in this case, it doesn't matter when it starts or ends) is Poisson distributed. You can just evaluate $P(0)$ (the probability that a lamp doesn't break in one hour) and then raise this to the $a$-th power, since you have $a$ independent lamps.

Comment: @nicola Thank you, I get the idea of using the poisson, but I didn't understand raising the power, I know that if we have $exp(\lambda)$, then $N_x\sim Pois(\lambda x)$ while $x$ is the length of the interval, so here I would get $N_1\sim Poiss(\frac{a}{b} 1)$ normally?. About what doesn't feel right about exponential memorylessness, is that I've always understood it as: if I know something, then I can apply it to my exponential R.V as I've explained, But here I don't understand what I know about my $X$ (time between breaks), I don't really know that it's greater than $2$ or less than $3$..

Comment: If $X$ is random variable that represents the event of a lamp breaking, we have $f_X(x) = b e^{-bx}$ and I would just find the probability of a lamp not breaking in that interval. Then use binomial to find probability that none of the $a$ lamps break in that interval.

Comment: @Pwaol We are both right. You can either think of a single lamp working $a$ hours (as you imply, I guess) or $a$ lamps working one hour each, as it was my suggestion. In this case, since the probabilities are independent, you have $P(\text{No broke lamp}) = P(\text{lamp 1 is not broken})  P(\text{lamp 2 is not broken})...$. Of course the two formulations are equivalent.

Comment: @nicola Nice! Thank you so much, I guess I will try always to use these in this type of questions as it is much easier, but I'll let the question up so I can clear my doubt about the memorylessness property, feels like I only know the basics of it and I don't understand it deeply enough